# Protractor wait for the page to fully load

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, jasmine, protractor

I'm trying to click on '0 - Bootstrapping' under Tutorial after going to https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial, but Protractor is not waiting for the page to fully load, so I get an Error

> Failed: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

I tried manually waiting for the page to load using

> browser.driver.sleep(10000);

but I still get the same Error.

conf.js

```
exports.config = {
// seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
getPageTimeout : 12000000,
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
},
specs: ['todo-spec.js'],
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 1440000,
}
};
```

todo-spec.js

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function () {
it('should greet the named user', function () {
    var dropdown = element.all(by.css('.dropdown')).first(),
        dropdownToggle = dropdown.element(by.css('.dropdown-toggle')),
        dropdownMenu = dropdown.element(by.css('.dropdown-menu')),
        menuItem = dropdownMenu.all(by.tagName('li')).first();

    browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');
    dropdownToggle.click();
    menuItem.click();

    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial');
    //waiting 10 seconds for the page to fully load
    browser.driver.sleep(10000);
    browser.waitForAngular();
});
it('', async function () {

    /*  tried waiting for the element to be present
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    var e = element.all(by.css('.nav-index-listing'))[0];
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(e), 10000);

    Failed: Cannot read property 'isPresent' of undefined
    */

    //clicking '0 - Bootstrapping' under Tutorial
    element.all(by.css('.nav-index-listing'))[0].click();
    expect(element(by.cssContainingText('.pln', 'npm install')).isEnabled()).toBe(true);
    // Failed: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

});
});
```

### Edit

Replaced

```
element.all(by.css('.nav-index-listing'))[0].click();
    expect(element(by.cssContainingText('.pln', 'npm install')).isEnabled()).toBe(true);
```

by

```
        element.all(by.css('.nav-index-listing')).get(0).click();
    browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.urlIs("https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00"), 5000);
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00');
    expect(element(by.cssContainingText('.pln', 'npm install')).isEnabled()).toBe(true);
```

And got an Error

> Failed: Wait timed out after 5001ms

If I remove browser.wait I get

> Expected 'https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial' to equal 'https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00'.

Comment: Please read the solution, it mentions to use `element.all(by.css('.nav-index-listing a')).get(0).click();` and not `element.all(by.css('.nav-index-listing')).get(0).click();`. You have to also mention the "a" tag in the selector.

Comment: Is it solved? If yes, then please accept the solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all `browser.driver.sleep(10000)` is not required. For page load, you can use `protractor.ExpectedConditions`. It will reduce unnecessary waiting for 10 seconds, if the page is already loaded.

Secondly, there is a minor mistake in your code which is the root cause of your problem.

Change this line

```
element.all(by.css('.nav-index-listing'))[0].click();
```

To this

```
 element.all(by.css('.nav-index-listing')).get(0).click();
```

**UPDATE:**

1. `element.all(by.css('.nav-index-listing'))` will only give you `li` elements which will pass the test. But clicking it, will not lead you to the desired page.
   Change it to:

   ```
   element.all(by.css('.nav-index-listing a')).get(0).click();
   ```
2. In this case, `[0]` will not work since the returned value is not an array. It is of type `ElementArrayFinder`. So, that's why `.get(0)` is required.
3. It will be better if you check for below conditions too, for your test.

   ```
   browser.wait(EC.urlIs("https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00"), 5000);    
   expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toEqual('https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00');
   ```

   These conditions checks whether your current URL is `https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00` or not.

Comment: Wow,Thanks a lot. I changed [0] to .get(0) and it really worked, even without waiting and stuff.But can you please explain why it works with  .get(0) and not with [0], cause I supposed that .get(0) and [0] were just two ways of doing the same thing(getting the first elementt from an array).

Comment: @KedelMihail I have updated the solution, to answer your question. As well as given some additional feedback which might help you.

Comment: When I use `browser.wait(EC.urlIs("https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00"), 5000)`   I get - `Failed: Wait timed out after 1002ms`

Comment: @KedelMihail This error is for different statement. It says, `Failed: Wait timed out after 1002ms`. That means there is 1 more "browser.wait" statement in your code, where you mentioned 1000ms as timeout and that failed.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `waitForAngualarEnabled(true)` instead of expected wait which makes the protractor to wait until all the angular elements are loaded and add `await` in every line of your test.

Comment: waitForAngularEnabled is enabled by default and is called every time you make a webdrive action (such as getCurrentUrl() or click()). :)